# Javascript animation - math issues

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to make a smooth javascript animation that makes a div slide from position left 900 to 550 on the screen..

With two variables; place and speed, I use place to locate where the div is on the screen, and speed to decide the speed.

To make this nice and flowy I've tried to make the speed go slower and slower, so the slide starts fast and goes slower and slower.

I don't know if I'm trying to do the right thing here, but basically, I want the speed to start at 100 %, lets say 50 px, and go a percentages slower for each time.

The speeds percentages should be equal to the number of my place.

So that place starts at 900, and ends at 550.
The speed should start at 50 and go a percentages slower for each time and end at 0 as the place ends at 550...

How do I set this up???

I've tried this:

```
function doit(place, speed, proc) {
    var denne = document.getElementById("screen1");
    if (place > 550) {
        var speedproc = 100 - (place / 950 * 100); // (the reason that I'm using 950 here is because it should have a percentage to start from that isn't 0)
        var newspeed = speed - (speed / 100 * proc);
        speed = newspeed;
        proc += speedproc;
        place -= speed;
        denne.style.marginLeft = place + "px";
        setTimeout("doit(" + place + ", " + speed + ", " + proc + ")", 20);
    }
}
```

And the body:

```
<body onload='doit(900, 50, 0);'>
```

But it acts out crazy... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not CSS 3 animations?

Comment: That would be easier.... Link?

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Also, CSS animations can be hardware accelerated by the browser! just google `CSS animations`

Comment: CSS animations: [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/), [smashing mag](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/14/the-guide-to-css-animation-principles-and-examples/) You could also just google it.

Answer (score 0):

All in all I would do something like this to create the slow down effect:

```
newspeed = speed*proc; //Now, proc is a number between 0 and 1.
//the closer proc is to 1, the smaller the decrease will be.
// when proc is 1 - there will be no decrease in speed
```

For example:

```
<body onload='doit(900, 50, 0.9);'>
```

Comment: There's no division by zero.  Multiplicative operators are evaluated left to right.

Comment: Roger that, didn't notice.

Comment: the number 0 is just to place a random value.. I could have set 1000 but that wouldn't make any difference as it calculates to speedproc and newspeed before adding denne.style.marginLeft = place + "px";
... Or what?

Comment: Still acts out the same that my proc is calculated before adding, so 0.9 or 1000000 doesn't make any difference...

Comment: yes, the problem I'm seeing is that you're recalculating proc on every iteration (`speedproc`). I'm trying to understand the logic behind the algorithm you came up with. And then the `proc += speedproc;` is even stranger... You're already changing speed, why would you change proc as well? [maybe double decrease (or increase)?]

Comment: Because when I just change speed it ends up very slowly at the end, but by decreasing the proc it makes some kind of difference.... i thought... But as said, my algorithm is clearly wrong, and can't figure out the logic behind... But think I'm going with css instead.. didn't know that I had that option.. :p